# how do I enable execution of php scripts in the per-user public_html directories

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script to upload files in a directory.
This works fine in apache's `DocumentRoot`.
When I copy the code in my `/home/$USER/public_html` , instead of the right output I just when a printout of the php file. I presume it does not get executed.

I was looking into the `userDir` module and found this

```
Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
```

`includesNoExec` looked promising but it is related to cgi only.

So how can I enable php scripts to be executed for every user?

Comment: This helped me: http://devplant.net/2010/05/04/linux-php-not-working-in-userdir-public_html/ and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the important bit of code that Claudix provided is already present in the configuration files under `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf`

the clause there contains `php_admin_value engine Off` , so by setting the Claudix solution anywhere will conflict with this setting. What is more, the comment above suggests NOT to set `php_admin_value engine On` as it renders `.htaccess` files unable to disable php.

As such the correct way to run php in user `www` directories is by commenting out the relevant text in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf`

Answer (score 4):

Try setting this configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine On
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: hi there.  I can not test if the code you sent is correct. I still get code dump in my uploadgile.php code when I run it from my users www dir. do you have some time to go through it in the chat with me?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using apache2 on debian like I do and I think the solution 
for you is to add Alias dir and set that alias dir config like below

1 edit the apache2 configuration from terminal run this command

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

2 edit the path you will to execute PHP files and save

```
Alias /testdir /home/user/testdir
<Directory /home/user/testdir>
    Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All   
</Directory>
```

3 restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

check If you can access the folder from browser if not probably you will have to chmod/chown the folder

yourhost/testdir

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache 2.2 documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html) this can be done by uncommenting this configuration line:

`#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

and modifying httpd-userdir.conf to suit your server. Based on your qustion text, this should resolve your issue.